# Converting Matlab code findpeaks() to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I've been working on converting a code from MATLAB to Python using the function findpeaks().

The matlab code is listed below:

```
[aux1, loc1] = findpeaks(sinwave,'MinPeakDistance', MPD,'MinPeakProminence',0.5)
gam1   = coswave(loc1)
n_loc1 = length(loc1)
```

The python code I've been working on is:

```
[aux1, loc1] = sig.find_peaks(sinwave, distance=MPD, prominence=0.5)
gam1         = coswave(loc1)
n_loc1       = max(loc1)
```

I am don't think I can call the MATLAB coswave(loc1) in the same way for the python script. I am also unsure about calling the [points, loc] for findpeaks() in MATLAB works the same as python does.  Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: Hi Rachel, you're making 3 mistakes. First, the output from the Python `find_peaks` function is first the indices (`peaks` in the documentation, `loc1` in your code) and second additional information about the peaks (`properties`). Your second error is that Python indexing is done with brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()`. If you look at the examples in the Scipy documentation I would think that would help: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html Finally, `max` is not a replacement for Matlab's `length` ...